# Как поменять аудиодорожки html5 видео с помощью javascript?

Tags: jquery, видео, html5, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Искал в интернете - нашёл способы с использованием videoTracks и audioTracks, но ни Chrome, ни Firefox не работает с этим. Хотя во всех примерах их используют.

Что делать?

P.S. На w3schools написано, что не один браузер ни поддерживает videoTracks. Неужели нету других способов?

Comment: @DeFF, проверяйте EDGE версии браузеров - от 15.01.15 в стандарте присутсвует videoTracks. Имейте ввиду, что в видео(в сам файл) должны быть вложены несколько дорожек сразу еще на этапе кодирования.

Comment: @stck если я вас правильно понял (но скорее всего нет), то у меня самые последние версии браузеров. С дорожками всё в порядке, нужно только суметь их переключить...

Comment: @DeFF, я имел ввиду Chrome Canary, Firefox Aurora, а там в js'е берёте элемент и делаете так, как в примере по ссылку выше указано.

Comment: @stck теперь ясно. Хорошо, буду пробовать. Спасибо.

Comment: @stck посмотрел в chrome canary, но там тоже не работает. Та же самая ошибка, которая и в стабильной версии :(